# Electron - IPC sending objects loses their instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

So I got an problem, when I want to send a Registry object with all my saved data from Main process to Renderer using IPC. But when transferring object it loses it's instance, so now it's just a plain object without any references. So when I want to call any function from Renderer on that registry, it says undefined, because it is undefined. Checking instance produces:

- Main:

```js
            LOG.log("Sending data: " + (this.mod.assetLoader.blocks instanceof AbstractFileExplorer))
            this.sendMessage('data:assets', {
                blockstates: this.mod.assetLoader.blocks
            })
```

Result: `Sending data: true` - object is an instance, correct

- Renderer:

```js
        this.receive('data:assets',(data) => {
        console.log("Received data: " + (data.blockstates instanceof explorer.AbstractFileExplorer))
        })
```

Result: `Received data: false` - object is not an instance

So, what can I do to leave references to that object, and to all it's content objects (I have a list of ResourceLocation object, which also loses reference).
For me it's just weird even to do it in separate processes, JavaFX has everything in one process and I can render and access files at the same time. Here I have to deal with sending objects that even does not have desired functions. Any way to change it?

Comment: I was trying with `remote` module, however it throws error, because it wants to execute function on main process, which has no access to `document`.

Comment: Your statement about JavaFX is wrong. JavaFX uses more than one thread and you are strongly encouraged to not run anything substantial on the main application thread.

Comment: Not really. From other threads you can do `new Runnable` which leads to main thread, but still - in that main thread - I can do both things - access files, data, open windows etc. and render

Comment: Not everything you can do is something you should do unless you are just writing yet another hello world program.

Comment: Could you please clarify on how you send (and want to receive) the messages? `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain`?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner this.sendMessage leads to ipcMainEvent.reply(<channel>, <data>), and receive in preload is: `ipcRenderer.send(<channel>, <data>);`, nothing special here. Reply on main is because I made a whole system that transfers messages between processes, it replies to event of message being sent on window open. Bit more complicated, but I don't think it can cause problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. You might be interested in investigating whether Electron's serialization of your messages causes your issues. Generally, anything that's not valid JSON is stripped. Have a look at [their documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)